# how do I read everything currently in a subprocess.stdout pipe and then return?

Tags: python, linux

I'm using python's subprocess module to interact with a program via the stdin and stdout pipes.  If I call the subprocesses readline() on stdout, it hangs because it is waiting for a newline.

How can I do a read of all the characters in the stdout pipe of a subprocess instance?  If it matters, I'm running in Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone else appears to have had the same problem, you can see the related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-stream-in-python).

If you are running on Linux you can use select to wait for input on the process' stdout. Alternatively you change the mode of the process' stdout to non-blocking using

```
import fcntl, os 
fcntl.fcntl(your_process.stdout, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

after which you can loop using read() until you encounter a newline character (if you want to process the output one line at a time).

Answer (score 2):

You should loop using read() against a set number of characters.

Comment: read() will block if there's currently no data in the pipe buffer