# Python: cannot read / write in another commandline application by using subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess, readline

I am using Python 3.0 in Windows and trying to automate the testing of a commandline application. The user can type commands in Application Under Test and it returns the output as 2 XML packets. One is a  packet and the other one is an  packet. By analyzing these packets I can verifyt he result. I ahev the code as below

```
p = subprocess.Popen(SomeCmdAppl, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,

                   shell = True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

p.stdin.write((command + '\r\n').encode())
time.sleep(2.5)
testresult = p.stdout.readline()
testresult = testresult.decode()
print(testresult)
```

I cannot ge any output back. It get stuck in place where I try to read the output by using readline(). I tried read() and it get stuck too

When I run the commandline application manually  and type the command I get the output back correctly as tow xml packets as below

```
Sent: <PivotNetMessage>
<MessageId>16f8addf-d366-4031-b3d3-5593efb9f7dd</MessageId>
<ConversationId>373323be-31dd-4858-a7f9-37d97e36eb36</ConversationId>
<SageId>4e1e7c04-4cea-49b2-8af1-64d0f348e621</SagaId>
<SourcePath>C:\Python30\PyNTEST</SourcePath>
<Command>echo</Command>
<Content>Hello</Content>
<Time>7/4/2009 11:16:41 PM</Time>
<ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
<ErrorInfo></ErrorInfo>
</PivotNetMessagSent>

Recv: <PivotNetMessage>
<MessageId>16f8addf-d366-4031-b3d3-5593efb9f7dd</MessageId>
<ConversationId>373323be-31dd-4858-a7f9-37d97e36eb36</ConversationId>
<SageId>4e1e7c04-4cea-49b2-8af1-64d0f348e621</SagaId>
<SourcePath>C:\PivotNet\Endpoints\Pipeline\Pipeline_2.0.0.202</SourcePath>
<Command>echo</Command>
<Content>Hello</Content>
<Time>7/4/2009 11:16:41 PM</Time>
<ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
<ErrorInfo></ErrorInfo>
</PivotNetMessage>
```

But when I use the communicate() as below I get the Sent packet and never get the Recv: packet. Why am I missing the recv packet? The communicate(0 is supposed to bring everything from stdout. rt?

```
p = subprocess.Popen(SomeCmdAppl, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,

                   shell = True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
p.stdin.write((command + '\r\n').encode())
time.sleep(2.5)
result = p.communicate()[0]
print(result)
```

Can anybody help me with a sample code that should work? I don't know if it is needed to read and write in separate threads. Please help me. I need to do repeated read/write. Is there any advanced level module in python i can use. I think Pexpect module doesn't work in Windows

Answer (score 1):

This is a popular problem, e.g. see:

- [Interact with a Windows console application via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124884/interact-with-a-windows-console-application-via-python)
- [How do I get 'real-time' information back from a subprocess.Popen in python (2.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874815/how-do-i-get-real-time-information-back-from-a-subprocess-popen-in-python-2-5)
- [how do I read everything currently in a subprocess.stdout pipe and then return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161580/how-do-i-read-everything-currently-in-a-subprocess-stdout-pipe-and-then-return)

(Actually, you should have seen these during creation of your question...?!).

I have two things of interest:

- p.stdin.write((command + '\r\n').encode()) is also *buffered* so your child process might not even have seen its input. You can try flushing this pipe.
- In one of the other questions one suggested doing a stdout.*read()* on the child instead of *readline()*, with a suitable amount of characters to read. You might want to experiment with this.

Post your results.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your input using `communicate` instead of using `write`:

```
result = p.communicate((command + '\r\n').encode())[0]
```

Comment: i have lots of input commands i need to send and read the output back. Is it possible with communicate?

Comment: Oh, now I get the problem. No, it's not. You should specify that in your question, that's important to know. I'll delete this answer then.

Comment: Please don't delete your answer... It helped.. But even the comminucate () missing the <Recv:> packet. It just gets the <Sent> packet only. What am I missing

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using pexpect instead of subprocess? It handles the details which are probably preventing your code from working (like flushing buffers, etc). It may not be available for Py3k yet, but it works well in 2.x.

See: http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html